# json_encode not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to convert my MYSQL table data into JSON. I am trying with json_encode(). But it does not work. It does not return anything. I have checked the console,doesn't even throw any errors. What am i missing?

```
<?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","maps") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "select * from locations";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
    $emparray[] = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);

    //close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Have you verified your query is actually returning results?

Comment: Yes, I have used the query in phpMyAdmin and it's returning results.

Comment: But that's not your code. Make sure it is returning results in your code.

Comment: can you do a var_dump($emparray); and check whether result is returning anything?

Comment: @aimme, yes var_dump() is returning results.

Comment: its not json. its var_dump :) , this means your sql is ok

Comment: Ya, now noticed its not JSON. sorry for being overexcited.

Comment: Still can't figure out why json_encode not returning anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $emparray[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo json_encode( $emparray );
```

or

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $emparray[] = json_encode($row);
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

or

```
$emparray = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode( $emparray );
```

instead of

```
 while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot for the hand. But why didn't it work earlier? Where did i go wrong?

Comment: wc :) actually each row is converted into  json, later whole together

Answer (score 17):

I know this is old, but I didn't found the explanation of this error, in my case, the problem was to keept the values on the DB with accent mark (Ej: cafetería). the var_dump($emparray ) certanly show information, but the echo json_ecode($emparray ) shows nothing. The solution?

This is my DB conection:

`$connection = mysqli_connect('ip,'user','pass','dbname')
or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));`

Only need to add the correct charset:

`mysqli_set_charset( $connection, 'utf8');`

Expetcs this work for others.

Comment: mysqli_set_charset( $connection, 'utf8');


Saved my life, friend, thank you.

Comment: This is Brilliant!

Comment: You saved my life, literally!

Answer (score 5):

Add this line and it will work fine:

```php
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same funny issue (using PDO) and in my case it helped to add the UTF-8 setting query - either of the two:

```
$conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");

$conn->query("SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;");
```

Comment: `$conn->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8;");` works for me whereas `$conn->query("SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci;");` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but when I tried the solutions above it returned me a 1-dimensional array of JSON-like strings instead of a 2-d array. I solved it by running `$.parseJSON` (jQuery) on each element.