# I want return JSON type but PHP return nothing

Tags: php, json

```
<<? php 
//PHP Version 5.2.17 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "ID", "password") or die ("fail");
mysql_query("set session character_set_connection=utf8;"); 
mysql_query("set session character_set_results=utf8;"); 
mysql_query("set session character_set_client=utf8;"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connect); 
$arr = array(); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){ 
    $arr[] = $row;
} 
echo (urldecode(json_encode($arr))); 
mysql_close($connect); 
?>
```

I want to return type `JSON`.
But this code returns only
**<[]**

When I do like this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){
  echo 'Firstname : ' .$row['Firstname '];
  echo ' Lastname : ' .$row['Lastname'];
  echo '<br/>';
}

echo $sql_result;
```

This code works normally.

I don't know why my code returns **[]**

my php version is 5.2.17

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `urldecode`.

Comment: And remove that rogue `<` at the start of your script..

Comment: @u_mulder I mis-hammered earlier and used my Golden Prybar, and now I cannot rehammer.  This question doesn't really need an answer.  What do you think of this dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672720/json-encode-not-returning-anything

Comment: Thank you for all. When I tried to print the code on like `aa.com/ex.php`, I knew it would be printed on `<[]`. Modifying the code and running it again in the main, it worked normally. The question is, is the value of array impossible to output in `aa.com/ex.php`?